# Book involving a very elderly woman going into a rejuvenation tank and coming out a young woman

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m looking for a book I read 20 years ago and really liked, but for the life of me I don’t know its name.  It involved a very elderly woman going into a rejuvenation tank and coming out a young woman.  She then gallivanted across Europe if I remember correctly.  Does anyone know this book and the name?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the SFF Stack Exchange :-) _Rejuvenation tanks_ are a pretty common trope in SF.  Is there nothing more you can remember about the book e.g. anything notable that the woman did, or any names or places in the book?

Comment: Partial match to Pandora's star(2004), with Justine burnelli getting rejuvenated then travelling far away at the start of the book and the time just about fits

Answer (score 7):

This is [Holy Fire](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4803) by Bruce Sterling (1996).  Ninety-four year old Mia Ziemann  undergoes a long treatment in a tank which gives her the body and brain of a twenty year-old, and then goes wild in the future European avant-garde art scene.

[You can read it on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/holyfire0000ster).

Comment: can such a thing happen and leave the person  the same person? just like i would not use the Enterprise's transporter, i sure would think twice about using technology like this.